# How to access data from json php and python

Tags: php, python, json

I have code like this to throw data from php to python

```
function fuzzy($id = '')
    {   
        $data_sg1 = core::selectWhereCollums('area_proses','default','sg1',array('id'=>$id));
        $data_sg2 = core::selectWhereCollums('area_proses','default','sg2',array('id'=>$id));
        $data_sg3 = core::selectWhereCollums('area_proses','default','sg3',array('id'=>$id));

        //contoh
        // This is the data you want to pass to Python
        $data = array($data_sg1,$data_sg2,$data_sg3);

        // Execute the python script with the JSON data
        $result = shell_exec('python "C:/xampp_2/htdocs/SkripsiV2/application/modules/admin/area_proses/controllers/fuzzy.py" ' . base64_encode(json_encode($data)));

        // Decode the result
        $resultData = json_decode($result, true);

        // This will contain: array('status' => 'Yes!')
        var_dump($resultData);

        /*
        core::update('area_proses','default',array(
            'fuzzy'  => $resultData,
        ), $id);


        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','success');
        redirect('area_proses');
        */
    }
```

when i want to access array in python like this

```
# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

z= 3.25162115490
# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'status': z}

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)
```

with that code in browser showing

array(1) { ["status"]=> float(3.2516211549) }

But i have a problem, when i change to this

```
try:
    data1 = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
    data2 = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[2]))
    data3 = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[3]))
```

The result is NULL

My question is how to access data from json in python?

Comment: did you try to print sys.argv[1] first? is it null? then try for print base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1])?

Comment: @DRPK when i print variable data the result is array(1) { ["status"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "3.71" [1]=> string(4) "3.48" [2]=> string(4) "3.30" } }

Comment: Why aren't you using the json data in the python code?

Comment: @gommb how to passing 3 data ? i try to passing 3 data to acess in python and acess 1 data in python, that the result

Comment: @gommb how to use that? i'm confused because i use php and process in python

Comment: You are only passing 1 arg in `base64_encode(json_encode($data))` so you can just use `json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))` to access everything in that.

Comment: when you print variable data you see array(1) ... ?!!! really? you print it in your php code or in your python code?!

Comment: @gommb but i have change the $data to array like this array($data_sg1,$data_sg2,$data_sg3);  how to acess the data in array?

Comment: @DRPK yes, in my php, but the value from the python like this

Comment: Just because $data contains multiple arrays doesn't mean it is passing in multiple arguments.

Comment: @DRPK # Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
    data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
except:
    print "ERROR"
    sys.exit(1)

# Generate some data to send to PHP
result = {'status': data}

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)

Comment: @DRPK the content is in result

Comment: @gommb how to solved ?

Comment: Can you tell us your expected result?

Comment: @gommb i have a meachine fuzzy, in the json result i want to parsing data with content z in result, example result = {'status' = z}, but i can't acess the data from json in $data with use (sys.argv[1])